# How do I make this button in XML?

Tags: android, xml, image, button, imagebutton

I wanted to make an ImageButton to put in my app, but I need a very specific one.

[image]

I wanted to make an ImageButton similar to that of the one in QuickPic. Notice on the left screenshot, the Camera. See how there's an image, with a translucent gray bar at the bottom with text in it? I wanted to make something very similar to that, but with one large textview in the gray bar instead of two small ones. I am completely lost on how to do this in XML so if someone could help me, It'd be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like this? :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />


<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:background="#33000000"
    android:text="Image Text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Additionally, you can specify the TextView's gravity and textSize to further match your needs:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:background="#33000000"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Image Text"
    android:textSize="8sp" />
```

Comment: It works, but the textview extends out horizontally, farther than the button does. Any way to fix that?

Comment: Edited Answer that should match your needs.